# Removing blocks of text from a file with bash

Tags: bash, sed

I am looking for a sane way to hollow out a function in Bash, I am not certain how to remove so much data using sed (though I feel either sed or awk would be the best solution here).

I have a file that has these function blocks in them

```
....

function InstallationCheck(prefix) {
 if (system.compareVersions(system.version.ProductVersion, '10.10') &lt; 0 || system.compareVersions(system.version.ProductVersion, '10.11') &gt;= 0) {
  my.result.message = system.localizedStringWithFormat('ERROR_0', '10.10');
  my.result.type = 'Fatal';
 return false;
 }
 return true;
}

function VolumeCheck(prefix) {
 if (system.env.OS_INSTALL == 1) return true;
 var hasOS = system.files.fileExistsAtPath(my.target.mountpoint + "/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist");
 if (!hasOS || system.compareVersions(my.target.systemVersion.ProductVersion, '10.10') &lt; 0 || system.compareVersions(my.target.systemVersion.ProductVersion, '10.11') &gt;= 0) {
  my.result.message = system.localizedStringWithFormat('ERROR_0', '10.10');
  my.result.type = 'Fatal';
  return false;
 }
 if (compareBuildVersions(my.target.systemVersion.ProductBuildVersion, '14A388a') &lt; 0) {
  my.result.message = system.localizedString('ERROR_2');
  my.result.type = 'Fatal';
  return false;
 }
 if (compareBuildVersions(my.target.systemVersion.ProductBuildVersion, '14B24') &gt; 0) {
  my.result.message = system.localizedString('ERROR_2');
  my.result.type = 'Fatal';
  return false;
 }
 return true;
}

....
```

I would like them to end up like this though

```
function InstallationCheck(prefix) {
 return true;
}

function VolumeCheck(prefix) {
 return true;
}
```

What is the most optimal way to achieve this?

**EDIT**

So everyone is aware, there are other functions inside this file that should remain unchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '/^function \(InstallationCheck\|VolumeCheck\)(/,/^ return true;/{/^function\|^ return true;/p;d}' file
```

Output:

```
....

function InstallationCheck(prefix) {
 return true;
}

function VolumeCheck(prefix) {
 return true;
}

....
```

---

Or with same output:

```
# first line (string or regex)
fl='^function \(InstallationCheck\|VolumeCheck\)('

# last line (string or regex)
ll='^ return true;'

sed "/${fl}/,/${ll}/{/${fl}/p;/${ll}/p;d}" file
```

Comment: How will this impact other function in this document though? Seeing how you are just matching `function` I believe it would bulldoze all other functions inside the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
inFunc && /^}/ { print "  return true;"; inFunc=0 }
!inFunc
$0 ~ "function[[:space:]]+(" fns ")[[:space:]]*\\(.*" { inFunc=1 }

$ awk -v fns='InstallationCheck|VolumeCheck' -f tst.awk file
....

function InstallationCheck(prefix) {
  return true;
}

function VolumeCheck(prefix) {
  return true;
}

....
```